# How can I make a javascript that works in html also work in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, html, razor

I have this html page I copied from [here](http://nicedit.com/demos.php). There is a javascript used that changes text areas into rich text editors. It works like it should when I just copy it in a file and open it with a browser. However, when I try to put it in my c# project and put it in a cshtml file (without changing anything) it ignores(?) the javascript and shows the textareas as plain textareas. How can I make this work in cshtml?

The code, same in html page as cshtml page:

```
<div id="sample">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
      //]]>
  </script>
  <h4>
  First Textarea
  </h4>
  <textarea name="area1" cols="35">
</textarea><br />
  <h4>
    Second Textarea
  </h4>
  <textarea name="area2" style="width: 100%;">
       Some Initial Content was in this textarea
</textarea><br />
  <h4>
    Third Textarea
  </h4>
  <textarea name="area3" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">
       HTML content default in textarea
</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong that is readily evident in the code supplied - could you post the entire code without displaying business specifics?!

Comment: Do you mean the javascript code? This is all the html code.

Comment: No, I mean the code that doesn't work `Razor` code...

Comment: Go research "javascript errors and how to find them" and let us know if you got any.

Comment: The error that I get is Uncaught ReferenceError: bkLib is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you copied and pasted the code into your cshtml, did you reference their copy of the nicEdit-latest.js file, or did you save a local copy of it.

As far as I can see it should work if you copied the HTML over exactly the way they have it.

try using the following if you are referencing a local copy of the js file

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE/nicEdit-latest.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**EDIT**
This should work.

Add a reference Jquery to if you haven't yet, and modify the code to look like this

```
//<![CDATA[
 $(document).ready(function() {nicEditors.allTextAreas() }) 
//]]>
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yenros/3jSGT/)

Comment: I copied it exactly like this

Comment: I'm not sure what bkLib.onDomLoaded is, but I get the idea they meant it needs to execute on page load :)

Comment: `bkLib.onDomLoaded` is defined in the script reference "http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js". @NiekdeKlein the reference to that library needs to come before anything that uses it...